# Replace spaces in bracketed text only in Postgresql by regexp_replace function

Tags: postgresql, regexp-replace

I need to replace all spaces in bracketed text only
`"Describe what you (tried and) what (you expected) to happen"`
with commas like this:

`"Describe what you (tried,and) what (you,expected) to happen"`

Please advise how to do it correctly using function regexp_replace.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not so easy to do with a simple `regexp_replace` function ...

If you have a maximum of two words in brakets then you can do :

```
SELECT string_agg (r.res, ' ')
  FROM ( SELECT CASE
                  WHEN elt ~ '^\(' THEN elt || ',' || lead(elt) OVER ()
                  WHEN elt ~ '\)$' THEN ''
                  ELSE elt
                END AS res
           FROM regexp_split_to_table('Describe what you (tried and) what (you expected) to happen', ' ') as elt
       ) AS r
 WHERE r.res <> ''
```

If you have two or more words inside the brakets then you have to create your own `aggregate` function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replace(x text, y text, old text, new text) RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql AS $$
  SELECT replace(COALESCE(x,y), old, new) ; $$ ;

CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE replace_agg (text, text, text)
(  stype = text
,  sfunc = replace
)
```

And the query is :

```
SELECT replace_agg('Describe what you (tried and) what (you expected) to happen', elt[1], replace(elt[1], ' ', ','))
  FROM regexp_matches('Describe what you (tried and) what (you expected) to happen', '\([^\)]*\)', 'g') AS elt
```

see the test in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y0e98wqA)